# Why is the walrus operator not a delimiter?

Tags: python, python-assignment-expression

The Python walrus operator (`:=`) is listed in the documentation as an [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators), but not as a [delimiter](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters) like the rest of the assignment operators (e.g. `+=`). Why then is the walrus operation not also a delimiter?

Comment: None of the operators listed there are also delimiters. The contexts that `:=` and `+=` can appear in have no overlap (i.e. if you replace one with the other without changing anything else, you will *always* get a syntax error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write “the rest of the assignment operators”, but there is only one assignment *operator* in Python, and that’s the walrus operator! The other assignment... thingies are delimiters in an assignment *statement*.

Comment: The spec is not entirely clear on this - it does not list `+=` and the like under "operators", but in the "delimiters" section it calls them "augmented assignment operators". So they aren't operators, but they also are a kind of operator, which is a bit strange. Nonetheless, this is basically the right answer - `+=` and the like cannot appear in the same lexical contexts as "proper" operators can.

Comment: And indeed ... `:=` is NOT allowed as a delimiter in an assignment statement.  An expression using `:=` must be within a larger expression, or within parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. The docs say "the augmented assignment operators...", hence I thought they were also operators. But this makes sense, they are delimiters that perform operations but are not lexically operators.

Answer (score 4):

The main reasoning for why its not allowed is to avoid ambiguity in code. More exceptional cases from [PEP 572 – Assignment Expressions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/)

> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level
> of an expression statement. Example:
>
> ```
> y := f(x)  # INVALID
> (y := f(x))  # Valid, though not recommended
> ```
>
> This rule is included to simplify the choice for the user between an
> assignment statement and an assignment expression – there is no
> syntactic position where both are valid.
>
> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level
> of the right hand side of an assignment statement. Example:
>
> ```
> y0 = y1 := f(x)  # INVALID
> y0 = (y1 := f(x))  # Valid, though discouraged
> ```
>
> Again, this rule is included to avoid two visually similar ways of
> saying the same thing.
>
> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited for the value of
> a keyword argument in a call. Example:
>
> ```
> foo(x = y := f(x))  # INVALID
> foo(x=(y := f(x)))  # Valid, though probably confusing
> ```
>
> This rule is included to disallow excessively confusing code, and
> because parsing keyword arguments is complex enough already.
>
> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited at the top level
> of a function default value. Example:
>
> ```
> def foo(answer = p := 42):  # INVALID
>     ...
> def foo(answer=(p := 42)):  # Valid, though not great style
>     ...
> ```
>
> This rule is included to discourage side effects in a position whose
> exact semantics are already confusing to many users (cf. the common
> style recommendation against mutable default values), and also to echo
> the similar prohibition in calls (the previous bullet).
>
> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited as annotations
> for arguments, return values and assignments. Example:
>
> ```
> def foo(answer: p := 42 = 5):  # INVALID
>     ...
> def foo(answer: (p := 42) = 5):  # Valid, but probably never useful
>     ...
> ```
>
> The reasoning here is similar to the two previous cases; this
> ungrouped assortment of symbols and operators composed of : and = is
> hard to read correctly.
>
> Unparenthesized assignment expressions are prohibited in lambda
> functions. Example:
>
> ```
> (lambda: x := 1) # INVALID
> lambda: (x := 1) # Valid, but unlikely to be useful
> (x := lambda: 1) # Valid
> lambda line: (m := re.match(pattern, line)) and m.group(1) # Valid
> ```
>
> This allows lambda to always bind less tightly than :=; having a name
> binding at the top level inside a lambda function is unlikely to be of
> value, as there is no way to make use of it. In cases where the name
> will be used more than once, the expression is likely to need
> parenthesizing anyway, so this prohibition will rarely affect code.
>
> Assignment expressions inside of f-strings require parentheses.
> Example:
>
> ```
> >>> f'{(x:=10)}'  # Valid, uses assignment expression
> '10'
> >>> x = 10
> >>> f'{x:=10}'    # Valid, passes '=10' to formatter
> '        10'
> ```
>
> This shows that what looks like an assignment operator in an f-string
> is not always an assignment operator. The f-string parser uses : to
> indicate formatting options. To preserve backwards compatibility,
> assignment operator usage inside of f-strings must be parenthesized.
> As noted above, this usage of the assignment operator is not
> recommended.